# How to pass powershell variable to groovy variable in Jenkinsfile

Tags: powershell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am writing pipeline in Jenkinsfile. And I have the problem. How can I pass powershell variable to groovy variable, or how can I manipulate with files within groovy in Jenkinsfile as I do via powershell?

```
     stage('GETTING SLN FILES') {
       steps {
           script {
               powershell """$dirs_with_sln = Get-ChildItem -Path . -Recurse *.sln | Select-Object -Property Directory -Unique
                             $slns = @()
                             foreach($dir in $dirs_with_sln) {
                               $dir = $dir.Directory
                               $FileExists = Test-Path -Path "$dir\\default.ps1"
                               if ($FileExists -eq $true) {
                                   $slns += $(Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Filter *.sln).FullName
                               }
                             }
                          """
    }
```

My solutions.json file :

```
[
    "D:\\ws\\workspace\\msbuild-test\\src\\DataProcessors\\AlertDelivery\\AlertDelivery.sln",
    "D:\\ws\\workspace\\msbuild-test\\src\\DataProcessors\\BusinessWireNewsProcessor\\BusinessWireNewsProcessor.sln",
    "D:\\ws\\workspace\\msbuild-test\\src\\DataProcessors\\ComponentMesosExecutor\\ComponentMesosExecutor.sln",
    "D:\\ws\\workspace\\msbuild-test\\src\\DataProcessors\\Crawling\\Core\\Agent\\CrawlingAgent.sln",
    "D:\\ws\\workspace\\msbuild-test\\src\\DataProcessors\\Crawling\\Crawlers\\Crawlers.Base\\_Crawlers.Base.sln",
    "D:\\ws\\workspace\\msbuild-test\\src\\DataProcessors\\Crawling\\Crawlers\\Crawlers.Custom\\_Crawlers.Custom.sln",
    "D:\\ws\\workspace\\msbuild-test\\src\\DataProcessors\\Crawling\\Crawlers\\Crawlers.Internal\\_Crawlers.Internal.sln",
    "D:\\ws\\workspace\\msbuild-test\\src\\DataProcessors\\Crawling\\Crawlers\\Crawlers.Reporting\\_Crawlers.Reporting.sln",
    "D:\\ws\\workspace\\msbuild-test\\src\\DataProcessors\\DocumentsMerge\\VADocumentsMerge\\VADocumentsMerge.sln",
    "D:\\ws\\workspace\\msbuild-test\\src\\DataProcessors\\Downloading\\DownloadProcessor.sln",
    "D:\\ws\\workspace\\msbuild-test\\src\\DataProcessors\\LogCollector\\LogCollector.sln",
    "D:\\ws\\workspace\\msbuild-test\\src\\DataProcessors\\MailProcessor\\MailProcessor.sln",
    "D:\\ws\\workspace\\msbuild-test\\src\\DataProcessors\\MailProcessor\\ProcessingAlgorithms\\CourthouseNewsAlgorithm\\InfoNgen.MailProcessor.CourthouseNewsAlgorithm.sln",
    "D:\\ws\\workspace\\msbuild-test\\src\\DataProcessors\\MailProcessor\\ProcessingAlgorithms\\DefaultProcessingAlgorithms\\InfoNgen.MailProcessor.DefaultProcessingAlgorithms.sln",
    "D:\\ws\\workspace\\msbuild-test\\src\\DataProcessors\\MailProcessor\\ProcessingAlgorithms\\HtmlNewsletterAlgorithm\\HtmlNewsletterAlgorithm.sln",
    "D:\\ws\\workspace\\msbuild-test\\src\\DataProcessors\\ProcessingUnit\\ProcessingUnit.sln",
    "D:\\ws\\workspace\\msbuild-test\\src\\DataProcessors\\SharePointDataLoader\\SharePointDataLoader.sln"
]
```

Comment: My way is PowerShell at the end output a JSON format text, Groovy read the JSON.

Comment: I did as you adviced. `$slns | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File solutionfiles.json` , `def files = readJSON file: "${workspace}\\solutionfiles.json"`  But I have error that : `hudson.remoting.ProxyException: net.sf.json.JSONException: Invalid JSON String`

Comment: You should probably output the result of that powershell command to stdout to verify it is correct JSON and what you expected.

Comment: I checked already. Everything seems ok with JSON data.

Comment: show the content of `solutionfiles.json` in your question.

Comment: Added the content of JSON file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example for you.

Your problem is `out-file` output with system default encoding, which is not `ASCII`

When pipeline read the text file, it's not able to recognize the first 1 or 2 bytes as `ASCII` characters. So, report the error.

So you can simply force output the json file in `ASCII` or read the json file content use the proper encoding.

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('1') {
      steps {
        script {
          powershell (script: "ls C:\\ | select Name, FullName | ConvertTo-Json | out-file C:\\Temp\\1.json -encoding ascii")
          def t = readFile("C:\\Temp\\1.json")
          def tt = (new JsonSlurper()).parseText(t)
          println tt
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```